# Get string indices from the result of re-seq

Tags: clojure

I'm currently using `re-seq` to find the matches of comments inside a piece of java source code.

```
(re-seq #"(?:/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*/]))*\*+/)|(?://.*)" code)
```

How can I get the index / indices of the matches in the original string `code`? i.e. To find the starting (and ending) point of the original string `code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `re-seq` with the requisite Java interop:

```
(defn re-seq-pos [pattern string] 
  (let [m (re-matcher pattern string)] 
    ((fn step [] 
      (when (. m find) 
        (cons {:start (. m start) :end (. m end) :group (. m group)} 
          (lazy-seq (step))))))))
```

Example

```
(re-seq-pos #"\w+" "foo bar baz") ;=>

({:start 0, :end 3, :group "foo"}
 {:start 4, :end 7, :group "bar"}
 {:start 8, :end 11, :group "baz"})
```

Comment: This is a partial solution for illustrative purposes. It does not descend into sub-groups as does `re-seq`. You would need a modified (as above) version of `re-groups` instead which you would call from a copy of `re-seq`.